# Parsing nested values in JSON

Tags: json, haskell

I have such an ugly part of code:

```
request <- parseUrl "someUrl.com"
res <- withManager $ httpLbs request
case decode $ responseBody res :: Maybe Aeson.Value of
  Just (Aeson.Object jsonObject) ->  
    case (HashMap.lookup "aaa" jsonObject) of
      Just a ->
        case a of 
          Aeson.Object jsonObject2 ->
            case (HashMap.lookup "bbb" jsonObject2) of
              Just b ->
                case b of
                  Aeson.Object jsonObject3 ->
                    case (HashMap.lookup "ccc" jsonObject3) of
                      Just c -> 
                        case c of
                          Array d -> 
                            case (d ! 1) of
                              String a  -> print a
                              _ -> error "error!!!"
                          _ -> error "error!!"
                      _ -> error "error!!"
                  _ -> error "error!!" 
              _ -> error "error!!"
          _ -> error "error!!"
      _ -> error "error!!"

_ -> error "Invalid JSON"
```

It does work well but it doesn't look good. How do I simplify it? I'm positive there is a way to do this. 
Note that I'm **not** using any custom data type for parsing a JSON and don't want to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`do` syntax for `Maybe` monad:

```
request <- parseUrl "someUrl.com"
res <- withManager $ httpLbs request
let toPrint =
  do Aeson.Object jsonObject <- decode $ responsBody res
     Aeson.Object jsonObject2 <- HashMap.lookup "aaa" jsonObject
     Aeson.Object jsonObject3 <- HashMap.lookup "bbb" jsonObject2
     Array d <- HashMap.lookup "ccc" jsonObject3
     String a <- return $ d ! 1
     return a
case toPrint of
    Just a -> print a
    Nothing -> "Invalid JSON"
```

Comment: I think the second last line of the `do` can be `let (String a) = d ! 1` rather than cycling it through a `Maybe`.

Comment: Well, here we specifically want `fail` function to be called if pattern doesnt't match. So, `return` it is.

Answer (score 8):

This problem—producing deep dives into large, complex data structures, is exactly what `lens` seeks to solve. The idea of `Lens`es isn't tough, but the package `lens` can be scary. I've written a few tutorials on this concept, however, which may be useful

- [Lens/Aeson Traversals/Prisms](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/tel/lens-aeson-traversals-prisms) provides an example of using `lens` to parse JSON
- [A Little Lens Starter Tutorial](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/tel/a-little-lens-starter-tutorial) goes through the whole `lens` package in a Socratic style.

In any case, for your particular example, we can replace this nested case with something like

```
print $ responseBody res ^!? key "aaa" 
                         .   key "bbb"
                         .   key "ccc"
                         .   ix 1 
                         .   _String
```

though I would recommend avoiding things like `error` to indicate failure. The `(^?)` combinators (also called `preview`) would help.